# Using AppMutex with silent Inno Setup

Tags: mutex, inno-setup

I'm using "AppMutex" in an Inno Setup script to make sure the product is not running anymore while installing an update. This basically worke fine.

But when running this setup with the "/verysilent" command parameter a dialog box is shown (although being very silent) that the program is still running and should be closed.

As the program itself is closed automatically and this may take only up to few seconds to be closed I just want Inno Setup to wait till the mutex was disposed and then start the installation, but not show any dialog box to the user in the meantime.

So is there a way to make Inno Setup just wait till the mutex was disposed when running with "/verysilent" and not show any dialog box about that to the user?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit way to suppress this message. However, you can suppress all the message boxes if you specify also the [`/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=SUPPRESSMSGBOXES) parameter for the command line:

```
setup.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES
```

If suppressing all the suppressible message boxes wouldn't fit to your requirements, you can wait for the mutex to be released (wait for your app. to terminate) by yourself in a loop with the [`CheckForMutexes`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_checkformutexes) function in an event fired before the setup performs this check.

Comment: Thank you very much!
That's everything I search for and totally enough. :-)

Comment: For an implementation of the solution with `CheckForMutexes`, see [AppMutex with Inno Setup: Wait few seconds before prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35088418/850848).